# What does "insertAdjacentHTML doesn't corrupt the existing DOM" mean?

Tags: javascript

```
insertAdjacentHTML() doesn’t corrupt what’s already in the DOM.
```

I just read this on the Mozilla blog about the implementation of insertAdjacentHTML(). What does it mean ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means it doesn't serialise the DOM inside the element to HTML, append the new HTML, then generate a new DOM from that (which would create new elements, breaking references, event handlers, etc).

Answer (score 0):

> insertAdjacentHTML() parses the specified text as HTML or XML and inserts the resulting nodes into the DOM tree at a specified position

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.insertAdjacentHTML